# Raw query doesn't accept where condition with date

Tags: sql, laravel

I have this Raw query, but when I run it I get a sql syntax error.

**here is the date params i use :**

```
    $last_week = Carbon::now()->subdays(7);
    $last_2_week = Carbon::now()->subdays(14);
```

**here is the query:**

```
DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(vd.qty_available) FROM products AS P
JOIN variations AS V ON V.product_id=P.id
JOIN variation_location_details AS VD ON VD.variation_id=V.id
JOIN transaction_sell_lines as ts ON ts.variation_id=v.id
JOIN transactions as t ON ts.transaction_id=t.id
WHERE t.transaction_date>=$last_2_week) AS last_2_week_quantity"),
```

**error** :SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Comment: Looks like there's a typo, an extra comma (`,)` at the end of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: maybe, there is nothing in the query. the date with which I make the condition .

Answer (score 1):

The actual SQL output will be similar to `WHERE t.transaction_date >= 2020-01-01 00:00:00`
which is invalid, you should wrap it in a single quotes.

something like

```
WHERE t.transaction_date>= '{$last_2_week}'
```

or better

```
WHERE t.transaction_date>= '{$last_2_week->toDateTimeString()}'
```

The `toDateTimeString()` forces the output to be in the correct format in this case.

or even better use the parameter binding

```
->whereRaw("... t.transaction_date>= ?", [$last_2_week->toDateTimeString()])
```

Comment: Ok @amd i will try it and tell you. Thank

Comment: It works very well, thank @amd you very much for saving your time.

Answer (score 0):

Put some space between the operand.
Instead of:

`WHERE t.transaction_date>=$last_2_week) AS last_2_week_quantity")`

Put:
`WHERE t.transaction_date >= $last_2_week) AS last_2_week_quantity")`

Comment: I try what you said , i have same error  @ml59, i will update the post with date params , may be the issue comes from this

Comment: Please edit your post an paste the full error message

Comment: here is the full message :Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000)
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe près de '10:58:17) AS last_2_week_quantity